# Worm fanfic where an anonymous Taylor teams up with a bird-suited hero named something like The Gobbler

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, worm

This is teasing at the edge of my head, but after several minutes of futile search attempts, I'm posting this here. It's a fanfic based on wildbow's *[Worm](https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)* universe. I read it somewhere in the last year or two, unfortunately among dozens that tend to meld together in my head. Taylor, the protagonist of the regular story, has a different set of powers (the details of which are, unfortunately, escaping me). For some reason, she wins up assigned to a B-Team of PRT capes, I think to allow her to build up experience while staying anonymous. I do remember that she wears armor almost constantly to protect her identity. The other things that pop into my head:

- Wherever it was had a lot of snow
- I don't think it was near a major city
- One of her new teammates is named something like The Gobbler

  - Their costume is a large bird suit, probably in the shape of a turkey
  - They gain various powers based on what they eat. I don't think they gain any sort of accelerated metabolism or ability to eat unusual things, so they have to bring food with them and exercise frequently  to keep the weight off
  - Since their group seldom actually has to fight, they primarily get called in to talk to schools about the importance of healthy eating
  - It's later revealed, maybe in a vignette from their point of view, that they used to be a minor criminal until an ill-advised attempt to use energy drinks to escape the authorities led to them sugar-crashing and getting captured
  - Despite that criminal origin, I remember them being fairly cheerful about being a hero, even if they're one that most people don't take seriously

Unfortunately, my searches for "gobbler" with keywords associated with *Worm* fanfic don't tend to fare very well because one of the prominent villains, Skidmark, has a tendency (at least in fanfic) to use "gobbler" with various bits of anatomy or scatological substances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. *[A Trilogy Without Save Files to Abuse](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Fanfic/ATrilogyWithoutSaveFilestoAbuse)* (warning, TV Tropes link), with the character being "Sir Gobbles" as per [this interlude](https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/a-trilogy-without-save-files-to-abuse-worm-game-mechanics.734380/post-58690544), although I misremembered what she consumed the time she got caught:

> The walls practically exploded as men in black uniforms burst in from the windows and doors.
> This wasn’t the first or even second time I had been caught but this time would be different.
> They always underestimated me, not even sending a Cape after me and now, with my preparations in place, I’d prove them wrong.
>
> Crunching down on my false tooth, the tablet I had in there was quickly swallowed.
> It wasn’t a suicide pill though, it was a drug, specifically cocaine.
>
> With my powers I could eat stuff and gain their effects at an accelerated rate.
> It wasn’t just about getting high on drugs quickly or more energy from coffee, it was all actual power, stuff that healthy eating and time couldn’t have done.
>
> In the case of cocaine, it gave me super speed.

....

> It was bullshit but it was better than being in the Birdcage I supposed.
>
> “Why am I wearing this stupid thing?”
>
> “The target demographic are kids.”
>
> “Yeah, I get that but why this specifically?” I turned around and the giant turkey tail knocked over a vase, something that I very much did on purpose but would deny if asked. To my disappointment, it didn’t break and was filled with a fake plant if the lack of dirt was anything to go by.

....

> “Remember kids, we got you covered!” Started Warranty.
>
> “Get plenty of sleep.” Added Flatout.
>
> “Eat your veggies.” I sang.
>
> “And listen to your parents.” Commander ended.
>
> They cheered as expected, not exactly a high bar to beat since they cheered as soon as we all lumbered in. They didn’t know better, they didn’t know we were uncool, at least, not yet.

The Taylor in question is going by the codename of Ebony Knight, having triggered with powers from *The Elder Scrolls: Skyrim*. It's the third story in that fanfic series, preceded by *[A Dovahkiin without Dragon Souls to spend](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Fanfic/ADovahkiinWithoutDragonSoulsToSpend)* where Taylor gets her powers and seemingly dies, only to get saved (and hidden) by secret organization Cauldron, and *[Sole Survivor Without a Radioactive Wasteland to Wander](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Fanfic/SoleSurvivorWithoutARadioactiveWastelandToWander)* where her father gets powers based off of *Fallout 4*.

I found it by searching TV Tropes for `worm fanfic gobbler`, which brought up the story.